# Value of integer variable being reassigned mysteriously

Tags: c++, integer, unsigned

I've got the following. A method foo:

```
template <typename II, typename OI>
    OI foo (II b, II e, int n, OI x) {
        // iterate
        int k;

        while (b != e) {
            ++b;
            ++k;
        }

        int iterations;
        iterations = k - n;

        cout << "k: " << k << endl; // output isn't 3, but some random large number
        cout << "n: " << n << endl; // output is 2
        cout << "k - n: " << 3 - 2 << endl; // output is 1
        cout << "k - n: " << iterations << endl; // output is 182741 or some random number

        return x;}
```

And my main method is as follows:

```
int main () {

    {
        const int a[] = {2, 3, 4};
        int x[10];
        foo(a, a+3, 2, x);
    }
}
```

My question is, in the above code, I'm trying to get the number of elements in the array that is passed in to foo, and I'm able to do that through k. Now I'd like to be able to subtract n (n = 2) from k, which would normally result in 1.

As soon as I do any subtraction involving k, though, k gets messed around with -- it goes from being 3 to being a signed random large number. I really don't know why this is. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: You didn't initialize k to 0; it could have any value.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I overlooked that. I forgot that initializing in a scope local to that function would result in undefined behavior...

Answer (score 3):

You have to initialise `k`, something like:

```
int k = 0;
```